# Sql Filter table by two dates in order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, filter

I have been trying to filter one table by two dates with an order of importance (date2 > date1) as follows:

```
SELECT 
    t1.customer, t1.weights, t1.max(t1.date1) as date1, t1.date2
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE CAST(date2 AS smalldatetime) = '10/29/2017') t2
INNER JOIN 
    table t1 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
             AND t1.date2 = t2.date2
GROUP BY 
    t1.customer, t1.date2
ORDER BY 
    t1.customer;
```

It filters the table correctly by date2 first, the max(t1.date1) doesn't what I want it to do though. I get duplicate customers, that share the same (and correct) date2, but show different date1's. These duplicate records have the following in common: The weight row is different. What would I need to do to output just the the customer records connected to the most current date1 without taking other columns into consideration?

I am still a noob, help would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution for t-sql** (all based on the accepted answer):

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT row_number() over(partition by t1.customer order by t1.date1 desc) as rownum, t1.customer, t1.weights, t1.date1 , t1.date2
    FROM 
         (SELECT *
          FROM table
          WHERE CAST(date2 AS smalldatetime) = '10/29/2017') t2
      INNER JOIN 
      table t1 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
      AND t1.date2 = t2.date2
     )t3
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Data structures?  Sample input?  Sample output?  What's wrong with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then instead of a group by logic, I would just use a qualify row statement :)

Try the code below and tell me if it's what you needed - what I'm telling it to do is to bring back only one row per customer ID....but where we select the row based on the dates (by sorting them in ascending order) - however, I'm unclear of what you mean by importance of the 2 dates so I may be completely off base here...can you please give an example of input and desired output?

`SELECT t1.customer, t1.weights, t1.date1, t1.date2
    FROM 
    ( 
    Select *
    FROM table
    WHERE Cast(date2 as smalldatetime)='10/29/2017'
    ) t2
    Inner Join table t1
    ON    t1.customer = t2.customer
    AND   t1.date2 = t2.date2
    Qualify row_number() over(partition by t1.customer order by date2 , date1)=1
    Order By t1.customer;`

Comment: I think, this is what I need, but for t-sql. I tried adjusting it accordently by additing "row_number() over(partition by t1.customer order by t1.date1, t1.date2)" to the select statement, but this doesn't output just the latest date1, rather lists them all.

Comment: Well if there's no qualify statements in t-sql (sorry never used t-sql before, just Teradata), you could ass this row num expression as an additional field and then filter data for the expressions being equal to 1. Cus what this does is create a numbered order for the rows based on the partitiom and order logic

Comment: Basically try adding this to the select portion: row_number() over(partition by t1.customer order by t1.date1, t1.date2) as rownum

Comment: and add a where clause that says where rownum=1

Comment: That's what I thought to, but the select clause gets processed last (at least that's how it seems) so it prompts me a "unknown column name 'rownum'"

Comment: ah that's easy to solve - wrap that query in brackets - and treat it as a table from which you select * with that where clause

Comment: of course, should have known that. Thanks!!! The good thing: It outputs just one record per customer. The not so good: Date1 doesn't filter by the latest date on record (11/7), but the earliest 11/2. I added ASC and DESC to the order by clause with no success.

Comment: k, got it done, yay! Thanks so much :) I just ordered by date1 rather than date1 and date2 and sorted in descending order. I will add the solution to my question and mark your entry as my final answer. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Yay! glad I helped :) No problem